possible to automatically turn connected TV on when opening laptop lid
I have a Dell laptop with a Westinghouse TV connected by HDMI cable, and Kubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. Every day when I open the laptop lid I have to manually turn on the TV with the remote control. Is there a way that KDE or Ubuntu could automatically turn the TV on when I open the lid?
Previously, I had a Windows laptop, and it would automatically turn the TV on when I opened the lid.
Update 1: I ran
xrandr --listmonitors

with the TV turned off, and the TV didn't show up. It's wierd that Windows had no issues with this, but (K)Ubuntu doesn't seem to even be able to see the TV when it's off?

not sure but have a look at KDE connect. Oh and do you know how windows does it? did you install software?

On the Windows laptop I didn't need to install anything. It just worked.
